# Is "how" in this sentence a conjunction?

Tags: conjunctions

Is "how" in this sentence a conjunction?

> I am learning **how** to use it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> *I am learning* [***how*** to use it].

*How* is not a subordinator here, but an interrogative adverb. The bracketed expression could be analysed as a noun phrase in a fused relative construction, especially as it can be paraphrased as *the way to use it*. On the other hand it could be analysed as an interrogative clause.

On balance, I think it is better to say that *how* is introducing a subordinate interrogative infinitival  clause (embedded question), where the meaning of the sentence is:

*I am learning how I should use it*

Comment: So these interrogative adverbs can act as both nouns and adverbs?

Comment: @BoSsYyY. No, it is an adverb, except in predicatives like "How was the concert?" where it is an adjective.

Comment: Ops. I wanted to say "a noun phrase" not "nouns". My bad. But anyway I have understood what you meant.

Comment: Can you also tell me what did you mean by saying "fused relative clause" because I've never heard it before. Also what is how in this sentence: "You don't know how bad is it"

Comment: @BoSsYyY I really think you should invest in a good quality up-to-date grammar textbook where you will find the answers to most of your questions.

Comment: I live in a non-English-speaking country and I hate reading things in my native language(miserable, poor, ungrammatical, ridiculous, senseless language). Also, I am student therefore I cannot afford to buy it

Comment: About my previous answer: I wanted to say "You have no idea how bad is it"

Comment: Does that matter? It's Bulgarian.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how some grammars define 'conjunction'. But from what I was taught, 'how' is simply called **an interrogative word**.

It functions like a marker of the subordinate interrogative clause, which functions as the complement of the verb 'learning'.

In subordinate closed interrogative clauses, the marker would normally be the subordinator 'if'`*`or 'whether' — e.g. *I know whether he accepted the offer*.

In subordinate declarative clauses, the marker is the subordinator 'that'. This subordinator is usually omissible — e.g. *I think (that) she doesn't like me*.

---

`*` <sub>The subordinator *if* is to be distinguished from the preposition *if* which is used in conditionals (e.g.***If** you go, I will stay here*).</sub>

Comment: User 178049 is right: a conditional adjunct most often has the form of a PP with the preposition "if" as head and a content clause complement, e.g. "I'll do it **if you pay me**".